# Mailcatcher: PHP mail() function returns false

Tags: php, email, mailcatcher

i will try to describe my problem:

to debug outgoing email in local environment i installed mailcatcher (http://mailcatcher.me/) but faced some problems with catching mails sent from web. if i run the script which contains only one mail() call, everything is fine and i can see the sent email in mailcatcher 127.0.0.1:1080. But when i try to access the same script from the web browser, the mail() function returns false, no any error displayed in browser, nothing in error logs. In mail log even i can see the call for mail() function.

i am not sure, may be my nginx/php-fpm configuration is wrong, or something wrong with permissions.

selinux is disabled.

please help if you know the solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: how are you running your test script manually? command line? note that PHP usually has TWO .ini files: command line + web-server embedded. If you configured mailcatcher in the CLI .ini file, then it won't work when you're running via webserver (SAPI mode).

Comment: i wrote, i run both ways, in command line it works, from the web does not.
with php.ini everything is fine, the at least the phpinfo() call get me the following for both cases:
sendmail_path /usr/bin/env catchmail

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem. Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same problem on ubuntu 14.04.

`/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` and `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` had the same `sendmail_path` configuration but only `php-cli` could send emails.

For my environment, `Mailcatcher` works on a distant server and I use the `catchmail` command to contact it.

Here is the `sendmail_path` I used:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/bin/env catchmail --smtp-ip mailcatcher-ip -f address@example.com
```

For the `fpm` `php.ini` file, I had to specify the full path to `catchmail` for the mail function to work correctly:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/catchmail --smtp-ip mailcatcher -f address@example.com
```

Comment: Did you change something with permissions because even with full path PHP-FPM is not able to run catchmail still!

Answer (score 3):

If you use Mac OS Sierra or later:
here is the right place of `catchmail`:

change `sendmail_path = /usr/bin/env catchmail -f catcher@mailcatcher.me`
By `sendmail_path = /usr/local/bin/catchmail -f someone@domain.com`.

Answer (score 2):

With php-fpm it works neat with the supplied wrapper script of RVM(?).

```
sendmail_path = /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/default/catchmail
```

Comment: When our hosting company updated PHP from 5.3.3 to 5.4.40 the "/usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/catchmail" no longer worked. The wrapper solution fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS 7 using PHP-FPM with PHP 5.6, I found that I had to modify `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` instead of adding ini files into `/etc/php.d` or modifying `/etc/php.ini`. This also required the full path as in @Alexis N-o's answer.

```
php_admin_value[sendmail_path] = '/usr/bin/env GEM_PATH=/usr/share/gems:/usr/local/share/gems:/usr/share/rubygems:$HOME/.gem/ruby /usr/local/bin/catchmail --smtp-ip 127.0.0.1 --smtp-port 1025 -f mailcatcher@example.com'
```

Update: more recently I found that GEM_PATH is nil when running php-fpm as apache on some environments. No matter what I tried (/etc/gemrc) I couldn't do it other than to inject `GEM_PATH` as part of this command.